# ayuda mod_rewrite php

Tags: php

Tengo una estructura de la siguiente manera:

- index.php
- .htaccess
- assets

  - app.js
- modules

  - main

    - default.php
  - demo

    - default.php

El .htaccess es:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)/?([a-zA-Z]+)?$ index.php?module=$1&view=$2 [L,NC]
```

EL index.php es:

```
<script src="assets/app.js"><script>
<?php
    $module = (isset($_REQUEST['module'])?$_REQUEST['module']:'main';
    $view = (isset($_REQUEST['view'])?$_REQUEST['view']:'default';
    include 'modules/'.$module.'/'.$view.'.php';
?>
```

cuando ingreso a la url **index.php** no tengo ningun problema, pero cuando ingreso a la url **main/default/** no encuentra el archivo **main/default/assets/app.js** , no sé a que se debe eso y como solucionarlo, gracias.

Comment: Usa asignación absoluta en los recursos .js y .css o bien usar el metatag base bien estructurado

Answer (score 2):

No creo que tenga que ver con mod_rewrite o el .htaccess, creo que es un asunto de como estás llamando el archivo .js, estás usando un enlace relativo al actual, intenta con:

```
<script src="/app/assets/app.js"><script>
```

Comment: EL problema es que estos archivos estan dentro de una carpeta en el servidor en la url **127.0.0.1/app** y cuando pongo lo que me indica me dice que no encuentra el archivo **127.0.0.1/assets/app.js**

Comment: Agrega entonces /app al comienzo, aunque dependiendo como esté organizado el proyecto puede haber una mejor solución. También ten en cuenta que puedes tener un problema de seguridad grande al llamar incluir los archivos de esta manera: `include 'modules/'.$module.'/'.$view.'.php';`